# sql query to exclude results if criteria is met

Tags: sql

i have a query which selects name, appointment date and their status icon. I want to exclude any records for the person if they have a status icon of 3.
Such as below:

| name | appt date | status icon |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bob | 11/11/2021 | 1 |
| bob | 11/12/2021 | 2 |
| jane | 11/12/2021 | 1 |
| jane | 11/12/2021 | 3 |
| jane | 11/13/2021 | 4 |
| tim | 11/11/2021 | 1 |
| tim | 11/11/2021 | 2 |
| tim | 11/11/2021 | 3 |
| karen | 11/11/2021 | 2 |

If i use where status icon <> '3', it still shows jane and tim. I want the query to only return bob and karen, as they don't have status icon values of 3.

Comment: Can you share your query that you have tried and doesn't give correct results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `NOT EXISTS`:

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (name VARCHAR(50), appt_date DATE, status_icon INT)
INSERT INTO @t1
VALUES
('bob','11/11/2021',    1),
('bob','11/12/2021',    2),
('jane','11/12/2021',   1),
('jane','11/12/2021',   3),
('jane','11/13/2021',   4),
('tim','11/11/2021',    1),
('tim','11/11/2021',    2),
('tim','11/11/2021',    3),
('karen','11/11/2021',  2)

SELECT t.name, t.appt_date, t.status_icon
FROM @t1 t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @t1 te WHERE t.name = te.name AND te.status_icon = 3)
```

| name | appt_date | status_icon |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bob | 2021-11-11 | 1 |
| bob | 2021-11-12 | 2 |
| karen | 2021-11-11 | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.name, A.appt_date, A.status_icon
FROM Table A
WHERE A.name not in (SELECT A1.name FROM Table A1 where A1.status_icon = 3)
```

What dogyog has suggested is also right but If you specifically want to exclude those names then you can use this query. Works perfectly fine.